# SIP service to be used for incoming call

Tags: android, call, sip

I am trying to automate incoming call to an Android Phone.

I have a sip client on my PC which supports call to Phone Number. For this I need a SIP account which will allow me to make a call to Actual Phone Number. This SIP service should be available in India and US.

I wanted to know

1. if I make a SIP call to a number will I get Incoming Call Notification in Android Phone?
2. Can any one guide me which SIP service I can use to have to make a call from PC to phone? This SIP service should allow 3rd party SIP client to connect to it. And also I want to generate just an Incoming call notification in Phone. So Please let me know if there any Free SIP service from which I can achieve this or some cheap service as Audio quality does not matter..

Answer (score 1):

You can use sip2sip.info and it's free. It supports [calls to PSTN networks](http://wiki.sip2sip.info/wiki/SipTesting). Check out how you can [configure your device](http://wiki.sip2sip.info/wiki/SipDeviceConfiguration).

Comment: Thanks Hovanessyan, sip2sip.info supports calls to PSTN networks but its not free. Is there no other VOIP provider which provides free calls to PSTN networks?